# Compare lists of objects where values matches

Tags: c#, epplus

> I have two lists of object like:
>
> List 1

| name | work_mail | work_telephone | private_mail | private_telephone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | mail1@job.com | 123 | mail1@private.com | 1230 |
| name2 | mail2@job.com | 456 | mail2@private.com | 4560 |
| name3 | mail3@job.com | 789 | mail3@private.com | 7890 |

> List 2

| name | work_telephone | work_mail | fax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name4 | 721 | mail4@job.com | 2341 |
| name1 | 123 | mail1@job.com | 3783 |
| name3 | 789 | mail3@job.com | 3712 |
| name5 | 276 | mail5@job.com | 3712 |

> This data came from two excel files, which i manage to put in two
> list. Now i have to merge the two list creating a third excel file,
> considering the work mail like an id. The result looks like

| name | work_mail | work_telephone | private_mail | private_telephone | fax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | mail1@job.com | 123 | mail1@private.com | 1230 | null |
| name2 | mail2@job.com | 456 | mail2@private.com | 4560 | null |
| name3 | mail3@job.com | 789 | mail3@private.com | 7890 | null |
| name4 | mail4@job.com | 721 | null | null | 2341 |
| name5 | mail5@job.com | 276 | null | null | 3712 |

> My code:

```
    internal static string MergeExcel(List<excelCell> list1, List<excelCell> list2) 
    {
        int key1 = 2;//position where the work mail is located
        int key2 = 3;

        using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            //Set some properties of the Excel document
            excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Admin";

            //Create the WorkSheet
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data");
            var counter = 1;
                foreach (var elem1 in list1.Where(y => y.column == key1))
                {
                    if (list2.Where(y => y.column == key2 && y.value ==elem1.value).Any())
                    {
                        if (counter== 1)
                            {
                                worksheet.Cells[1, counter].Value = elem1.value;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                worksheet.Cells[counter,1].Value = elem1.value;
                            }
                        }
                        counter++;
                }
                //Save your file
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path + "FileC" + ".xlsx");
            excelPackage.SaveAs(fi);
        }
        return "Excel file output";
    }
```

> but I can't figure how to properly iterate through the lists, my
> result:

| work_mail |
| --- |
| mail1@job.com |
| mail3@job.com |

Comment: Looks like you're only adding one value to the new excel sheet in your loop, which must be the work mail. You'd need to add all the values

Comment: @davidsbro yes but I don't know how to say:
`if(work_mail of list1.Equal(work_mail of list2))
then check if the corresponding name of list1 ==name of list2. If so add it to worksheet.Cells[row 2, column 2].Value = elem1.value`
And so on with work_telephone on row 2 column 3 etc